# Filtering related entities with Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, filtering

I'm looking for the best way to to load and filter related child entities. I have something that works, but I'm unsure if it's the best or even the right way to achieve what I want. Working code example below. Pros and cons would be great! Thanks!

```
public Site Find(int siteID)
{
    // Can't use include here, not possible to filter related (child) entities
    // return _context.Sites.Where(x => x.ID == siteID)
    //                      .Include("SiteLoggers")
    //                      .Where(x => x.Deleted == false)
    //                      .FirstOrDefault();

    var site = _context.Sites.Where(x => x.ID == siteID).FirstOrDefault();

    if(site != null)
    {
        site.SiteLoggers = site.SiteLoggers.Where(x => x.SiteID == siteID && 
                                                       x.Deleted == false)
                                           .ToList();
    }

    return site;
}
```

EDIT:

Added POCOS

```
public class Site
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SiteLogger> SiteLoggers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LinkDcSite> DcSiteLinks { get; set; }
}

public class SiteLogger
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UID { get; set; }
    public int SiteID { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SiteLoggerSensor> SiteLoggerSensors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LinkLoggerSiteLogger> LinkLoggerSiteLogger { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method is fine I think you have just extra checking for `x.SiteID == siteID`:

```
....
site.SiteLoggers = site.SiteLoggers.Where(x => !x.Deleted).ToList();
....
```

Also if you searching by ID means you are sure there is no two element with same ID, so it's better to use SingleOrDefault instead of FirstOrDefault, to throw an exception in the case there are more than one item with one ID.

```
var site = _context.Sites.Where(x => x.ID == siteID).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hi. Have do so. What you think about my comments on the other post?

Comment: If you need `site` you shouldn't get it by its child.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a simple query:

```
var site = _context.SiteLoggers.Where(sl => sl.SiteId = siteId && !sl.Deleted).ToList();
```

If there's a relation between SiteLoggers and Sites, you don't need to chek that the site exists.

Comment: Hi. In you example your query just returns a collection of SiteLoggers not a site, but are you saying that I can get the site via the SiteLoggers collection? I.e var siteLoggers = _context.SiteLoggers.Where(x => x.SiteID == siteID && !x.Deleted);

            Site site = null;

            if (siteLoggers != null)
                site = siteLoggers.FirstOrDefault().Site;
            
            return site;

Comment: Sure you can, but not in that way. Are you using DbContext or ObjectContext? Thing are a bit different. You should read about eager loading, lazy loading and explciit loading. It also depends on your model. Does a relation between site & siteloggers exist? What kind of relation. There's a lot of missing info to give a full answer

Comment: Hi. I'm using DbContext. Yes there is a relation as you can see in the POCOs. I'm no expert but I did do some research on the eager,lazy, explicit loading. That's why I originally used the include method as it seemed a good idea to eager load the related SiteLoggers given that there will only be 5 or so?